# Filetype is NET? Other sites on server are "folder"

Tags: centos, website, centos-6

I am curious as to why two sites on my Centos 6 server are "NET" as the filetype.

Does it make a difference vs a folder?

Here is a picture for better understanding: 
[image]

As you can see, amazonaffiliates.net and travisingram.net both have a NET file type.

Now that I look at it, maybe cause the sites are .net But can this make things any different for my sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'filetype' is just a 'handy' description of the type of file/folder that is in the view. Sometimes it will see the file or folder's ending is '.whatever' and it will simply say that it's a 'WHATEVER file' (regardless if it's a folder). It could be thought of as a bug in the GUI for not detecting that the 'filetype' shouldn't logically apply to any folders, but that's essentially what's happening.

tldr: it won't affect any of your files/sites.

If it might bug you that much let us know what GUI (Gnome, KDE, Fluxbox, etc.) you are using and there might be a way to 'fix' it through some config file.